# C++ Eigen index-wise operation (equivalent to R tapply)

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a question regarding the Eigen library. I want to compute the min (or the sum) of the elements of a vector (say `v`) when grouping these elements depending on another vector (say `i`) which defines groups of values.

```
Eigen::vectorXd v(10); // values
v.setLinSpaced(10,1,10); // 1, 2, ...10
Eigen::vectorXi i(10); // labels
i << 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3; // 3 different groups with label 1, 2 or 3
```

I want to do a group-wise or index-wise operation, i.e. get the min for groups of values in `v` that are defined in `i`: minimum of values in `v` corresponding to indexes of entries in `i` equal to 1, same for entries in `i` equal to `2` and for entries in `i` equal to 3.

```
Eigen::vectorXd m(3); // group-wise min (here I have 3 groups)
m = v.XXXX(i); // what I want: 1, 4, 7 given by function XXXX
```

In other word, I am looking for an equivalent of the `tapply` function in R (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/tapply.html).

I am currently doing it manually by extracting values in `v` for each group in `i`. Hopefully, there exists another way.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
If there exists a method so that I could just extract values in `v` for which entries in `i` are equal to 1 (or 2 or 3), that would be a great start.

Comment: Is `i` always sorted? What shall happen if `i` has values which are negative or larger than `m`?

Comment: The vector `i` of groups/classes might not be sorted. Values in `i` correspond to labels, they could be negative, just there is as many group as there are unique values in `i`. In my example there are 3 groups labelled 1,2 and 3, but they might as well be labelled -10, 50, 25.